# Strange way of overloading the dereference operator from a BoostCon talk

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I was watching a boostcon talk on youtube titled "Introduction to Modern C++ Techniques (Part I)". Around minute 22 the speaker shows a class which overloads the dereference operator.

```
template<typename T,
         typename CheckingPolicy = NoChecking,
         typename BadPointerPolicy = BadPointerDoNothing>
class pointer_wrapper
{
public:
    pointer_wrapper() : value_(0) {}
    explicit pointer_wrapper(T* p) : value_(p) {}

    operator T*()
    {
        if ( ! CheckingPolicy::check_pointer(value_) )
        {
            return BadPointerPolicy::handle_bad_pointer(value_);
        }
        else
        {
            return value_;
        }
    }

private:
    T* value_;
};
```

I have never seen this way of overloading the dereference operator. Why is there no return type and why does the T appear after the 'operator' keyword?
I always thought the way to overload this operator was like this:

```
T& operator *()
{
    // ...
    return *value_
}
```

If anybody is interested, [here is the talk](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9TFV2JxX7L0&feature=g-user-u)

Comment: It's not the dereference operator, but a type-casting operator.

Comment: @Joachim Yes, that's right. I totally forgot about that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `implicit conversion operator to type T*`.
n3337 12.3.2/1

> A member function of a class X having no parameters with a name of the form
>
> conversion-function-id:
>
> operator conversion-type-id
>
> conversion-type-id:
>
> type-specifier-seq
> conversion-declaratoropt
>
> conversion-declarator:
>
> ptr-operator conversion-declaratoropt
>
> specifies a **conversion from X to the type specified by the conversion-type-id**. Such functions are called
> conversion functions. No return type can be specified.
>
> **If a conversion function is a member function, the
> type of the conversion function (8.3.5) is “function taking no parameter returning conversion-type-id”**.

Comment: Damn, I actually knew this, but I forgot that you could do that. I read about it once, but never used it. Thanks a lot.